# How do i find the distance between two points/pixels?

Tags: c#, geometry, distance

I have this method:

```
private static List<Point> ExtendPoints(Point pt1, Point pt2)
{
    List<Point> ExtendedPoints = new List<Point>();
    decimal i = (Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(Math.Abs(pt1.X - pt2.X), 2) + Math.Pow(Math.Abs(pt1.Y - pt2.Y), 2) + Math.Pow(Math.Abs(z1 - z2), 2)));

    return ExtendedPoints;
}
```

I need to find the exact x and y coordinate between the two points pt1 and pt2.
The result should for example: 12,13 and this coordinate is exactly in the middle between the two points.

The way im doing it now with the decimal and the Math calculation is not the right way.

Comment: On a side note, a well established C# coding convention is such that `ExtendedPoints`, being a local variable, should start with lower-case (`extendedPoints`), just like `i`. Otherwise it looks misleading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add the value of the components and divide by 2:

```
private static Point MidPoint(Point pt1, Point pt2)
{
    var midX = (pt1.X + pt2.X) / 2;
    var midY = (pt1.Y + pt2.Y) / 2;
    return new Point(midX, midY);
}
```

Mind you, not sure which `Point` class you're using. If it's [`System.Drawing.Point`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.point%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you may have issues with integer truncation.

Also, I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the `List<Point> ExtendedPoints` as, as far as I'm aware, there's only 1 midpoint between two points. I'm also not sure what you're doing with the `z1` and `z2`. If you're using 3 dimensional points, you can extend my answer and add the third dimension easily.

Answer (score 3):

Why not this

```
double dist = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(x2 - x1, 2) + Math.Pow(y2 - y1, 2));
```